# How to detect tap on particular line on UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextview` i want to make few words as link so that i can detect tap on them and get a callback function. I have made link property of `UITextView` as checked and Implemented below delegate methods.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    print("hello")
    return true
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    print("bye")
    return true
}
```

I have also made the string bold and italic by using `NSMutableString`

```
let str = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.tvBottom.text as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
str.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "http://www.google.com", range: NSRange(location: 4, length: 14))
str.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue , range: NSRange(location: 4, length: 14))
let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]
str.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: NSRange(location: 4, length: 14))
str.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName , value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 4, length: 14))
self.tvBottom.attributedText = str
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you need to enable link property on UITextView

Answer (score 0):

To detect a tap on a particular line (as your question's title suggests), then the following code would do the job:

```
func didTapTextView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .recognized {
        let location = recognizer.location(ofTouch: 0, in: textView)

        if location.y >= 0 && location.y <= textView.contentSize.height {
            guard let font = textView.font else {
                return
            }

            let line = Int((location.y - textView.textContainerInset.top) / font.lineHeight) + 1
            print("Line is \(line)")
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is used to call the method above when a tap is detected on our textView.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapTextView(recognizer:)))
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

However, if you only want to detect taps on links, then you should conform to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol, and implement the following method:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Of course, you need to add the delegate to your textView (e.g. in `viewDidLoad()`)

```
textView.delegate = self
```

P.S. your `UITextView` should not be editable.

Comment: if line is first but i want to detect on which word user tapped on UITextView

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: let say i have a paragraph "This is just a very very great product.Please **click here** to view more".Now only on **Click Here** i want to detect the tap